# Can the "PATCH" method be used more than once in Laravel for the same entity?

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-10

I am creating a small program for access control.

I had a "PATCH" for the update and now that I'm doing the exit function, I added another "PATCH" for that method in the routes, now when I go to edit it tells me that the route I'm calling doesn't exist.

My routes

```php
Route::get('/bitacora/create', [BitacoraController::class, 'create'])->name('bitacoras.create');
Route::post('/bitacora', [BitacoraController::class, 'store'])->name('bitacoras.store');
Route::get('/bitacora/{bitacora}', [BitacoraController::class, 'show'])->name('bitacoras.show');
Route::get('/bitacora/{bitacora}/edit', [BitacoraController::class, 'edit'])->name('bitacoras.edit');
Route::patch('/bitacora/{bitacora}', [BitacoraController::class, 'update'])->name('bitacoras.update');
Route::patch('/bitacora/{bitacora}', [BitacoraController::class, 'salida'])->name('bitacoras.salida');
Route::delete('/bitacora/{bitacora}', [BitacoraController::class, 'destroy'])->name('bitacoras.destroy');
```

I tried changing the order of the routes as I know they have a certain "hierarchy", but I'm just getting started in Laravel and I'm not entirely sure how it works.

Comment: You can't have two `route::patch()` routes using the same URL. Only the first one will work, so you'd need to change the URL. Could `Route::patch('/bitacora/{bitacora/}/salida', ...` work instead?